# Как по нажатии на кнопку выключить телефон?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Подскажите пожалуйста, как по нажатию на кнопку выключить телефон.

Я гуглил, но не смог найти работающий способ. Также я читал официальную документацию, но там было написано, что это устарело.

Если вы знаете, как по кнопке отключить телефон, скажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Обычным способом никак. Только системные приложения и root пользователь могут такое делать.

Comment: если бы была такая же возможность, то первый же вирус заблокировал миллиарды устройств

Answer (score 0):

Быстро пробежавшись по документации к классу PowerManager, нашел в нем метод `reboot(String reason)`. Думаю он позволит только перезапустить устройство. Инициализация
`pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);`
Так же вы можете вешать слушателей на кнопки громкости, если нужна помощь с этим, прошу в комментарии.

Comment: Спасибо,но мне нужна не перезагрузка,а просто выключение телефона